AWS aws_wafv2_web_acl rule and_statement syntax in terraform
I am trying to write terraform code to create a WAF rule to block any POST request that does not have Content-Type: application/json.
Terraform documentation is not clear on the syntax.  Below is my code:
  rule {
    name     = "my-block-post-requests-content-type-application-json"
    priority = 7

    action {
      block {}
    }

    statement {
      and_statement {
        statements = [
          {
            byte_match_statement = {
              field_to_match {
                method {}
              }
              positional_constraint = CONTAINS
              search_string         = POST
              text_transformation {
                priority = 0
                type     = NONE
              }
            }
          },
          {
            not_statement {
              statement {
                byte_match_statement {
                  search_string = "application/json"
                  field_to_match {
                    single_header {
                      name = "content-type"
                    }
                  }
                  positional_constraint = CONTAINS
                  search_string         = POST
                  text_transformation {
                    priority = 0
                    type     = NONE
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "${var.solution}-${var.environment}-block-post-requests-content-type-application-json"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }


But it is giving this error:
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
╷
│ Error: Missing key/value separator
│ 
│ On waf.tf line 249: Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of
│ the attribute value.
╵

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


Line 249 is the actually line no 14 in the previous code block.  It is also showing red squiggly(wavy) lines in Vscode editor.  I would highly appreciate any hint on resolving this error.
Here is the snapshot of the rule(which I created manually) from AWS console:

The Json text from AWS console for this rule:
{
  "Name": "Block-post-Content-Type-Application-Json",
  "Priority": 8,
  "Statement": {
    "AndStatement": {
      "Statements": [
        {
          "ByteMatchStatement": {
            "SearchString": "POST",
            "FieldToMatch": {
              "Method": {}
            },
            "TextTransformations": [
              {
                "Priority": 0,
                "Type": "NONE"
              }
            ],
            "PositionalConstraint": "CONTAINS"
          }
        },
        {
          "NotStatement": {
            "Statement": {
              "ByteMatchStatement": {
                "SearchString": "application/json",
                "FieldToMatch": {
                  "SingleHeader": {
                    "Name": "content-type"
                  }
                },
                "TextTransformations": [
                  {
                    "Priority": 0,
                    "Type": "NONE"
                  }
                ],
                "PositionalConstraint": "CONTAINS"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "Block-post-Content-Type-Application-Json"
  }
}


The field_to_match argument is the one that's causing the issue?

@MarkoE Yes, but I don't think that's the issue.  I tried many possible combinations.  Also checked code syntax in ChatGPT but that also didn't work.

Here is the fixed terraform
resource "aws_wafv2_rule_group" "this" {
  capacity    = 20
  name        = "Testing"
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  rule {
    name     = "Block-post-Content-Type-Application-Json"
    priority = 0
    action {
      block {
      }
    }
    statement {
      and_statement {
        statement {
          byte_match_statement {
            positional_constraint = "CONTAINS"
            search_string         = "POST"
            field_to_match {
              method {}
            }
            text_transformation {
              priority = 0
              type     = "NONE"
            }
          }
        }
        statement {
          not_statement {
            statement {
              byte_match_statement {
                positional_constraint = "CONTAINS"
                search_string         = "application/json"
                field_to_match {
                  single_header {
                    name = "content-type"
                  }
                }
                text_transformation {
                  priority = 0
                  type     = "NONE"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "Block-post-Content-Type-Application-Json"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }
  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    metric_name                = "Testing"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
  }
}

Additional note:
You should not be using
statements = [

or

byte_match_statement = {

Instead it should be
statement {

and

byte_match_statement {

Also if you are ever confused on creating the terraform, you can create the waf rule through console first then with terraform v1.5.0 or newer do https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import/generating-configuration
import {
    id = "12345678-90ab-cdef-1234-567890abcdef/NAME/REGIONAL"
    to = aws_wafv2_rule_group.this
}

Then run
terraform plan -generate-config-out=generated_resources.tf

